# Execute command during the installation PIP package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

If I understand correctly, during the installation PIP package unpack the archive with application. I need to create a file in `/usr/local/bin/`. How to executo custom python commands during the installation PIP package?

Comment: Is it possible to package the file and distribute it that way? Running custom Python commands during pip installation can be done (in setup.py) but should be avoided if possible.